# Dynamic Dropdown in Datatable plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, datatables-1.10

I am currently using the datatable with datatable plugin.I also added the checkbox and dynamic dropdown with it.Now when i click the checkbox i can't able to get the selected value from datatable

it brings the html code?How can i get the value?

Answer (score 0):

Please called below function on onchange event of checkbox.

```
onChangeCheckBox(_id)
```

In function pass same id of dropdown i.e. '_id'.

```
function onChangeCheckBox(e) {
    var id = e.id;
    var val = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    var text = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
}
```